# Math.cos not working

Tags: java, trigonometry

This bit of my program is supposed to calculate bottomAngle using cosine rule.

```
public double bottomAngle() {

        topAngleinRadians = Math.toRadians(topAngle) ;

        return (Math.cos(topAngleinRadians)(bottomAngle() = ladderLength^2 + floorLength^2 - verticalHeight^2) / 2 * ladderLength * floorLength) ;
        }
```

Errors produced:
[image]

Here is my list of errors and I can't figure it out what's wrong with my formula. All the methods such verticalHeight , ladderLength works perfectly fine in other methods. There is something wrong with the way I put this formula. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Post your list of errors here.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this line `bottomAngle() = ladderLength^2 + floorLength^2 - verticalHeight^2` ?

Comment: I can't figure out what you expect that `return` statement to do, but it doesn't seem to make any sense. Why is it calling itself?

Comment: Are you trying to use `^` as power? If so, it's not doing what you expect. That symbol is actually bitwise exclusive OR in java. Try using Math.pow instead.

Comment: Why are you having a `method call` that on `LHS`?

Comment: Your code is meaningless. Try legal Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing your list of errors, you do have syntax errors:

`return (Math.cos(topAngleinRadians)(bottomAngle() = ladderLength^2 + floorLength^2 - verticalHeight^2) / 2 * ladderLength * floorLength);`

- You have no operator between your call to `Math.cos()` and the next part of your expression.
- You're also appear to be assigning values to a function call, which doesn't make sense.
- The `^` operator is also not the exponential operator, but a bitwise exclusive OR operator. You're probably looking for `Math.pow()`.

Those are just what I'm seeing right off the top. It might be helpful to read up about the Java [operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and how they are evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few issues here.

**Multiplication** - unlike in regular algebra, you have to explicitly define that you want multiplication between two expressions `Math.cos(topAngleinRadians)*...`

**Assignment** - you appear to be trying to assign something to a method call (`bottomAngle() = ...`). This is not really something you can do, and I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve by it.

**Squaring** - `10^2` does not square `10` into `100` in java, but is rather the `XOR` (exclusive OR) operator. You probably want to use `Math.pow(ladderLength, 2)` or simply `ladderLength * ladderLength`

Answer (score 2):

Unlike algebraic notation, Java parentheses do not implicitly multiply.

You need to insert a `*` between `)(`.

Comment: There's more to it: `bottomAngle() = ...` is not going to work either :)

Comment: And there's that pesky "^" syntax.  I think the OP wants exponentiation; but in Java "^" instead means "XOR".

Answer (score 1):

Can't really understand the purpose of your return statement, but I would rather break the statement into 2-3 lines to make it more readable: -

```
public double bottomAngle() {

        topAngleinRadians = Math.toRadians(topAngle) ;


        double bottomAngle = Math.pow(ladderLength, 2) + Math.pow(floorLength, 2) - 
                             Math.pow(verticalHeight, 2);

        double denom = 2 * ladderLength * floorLength;
        double numerator = bottomAngle * Math.cos(topAngleinRadians);

        return numerator / denom ;
}
```

Note that, `3 ^ 2` does mean `3 squared` in Java. You would need `Math.pow` method for that.

Also, you need to check why you were having `bottomAngle()` method call on LHS. I have assumed it to be a temp variable here.

As you can see, your code looks much more readable. And it becomes easy to find out compiler errors.

Comment: @JoelWestberg. Yeah edited it. Was a copy paste, so didn't noticed it first time :)

Answer (score 0):

Your sytnax is incorrect. Parenthesis do not mean mutliplication, you need explicit * (multiplication operator). Also, you have some other mistakes:

```
Math.cos(topAngleinRadians)(bottomAngle() = ladderLength^2 + floorLength^2...
```

this looks like a method call i.e. bottomAngle() being set equal to some other expression, this is invalid also..